# AWS Lambda in Python fail to import module

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have a very simple Python I need to use as an AWS Lambda function:

```
import pyodbc


def lambda_handler():
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                      "Server=AAA;"
                      "Database=BBB;"
                      "UID=CCC;"
                      "PWD=DDD;")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO [dbo].[log]([opened_by_id],[open_timestamp],[type_id],[title]) VALUES(118,GETDATE(),1,'test_1')")
cnxn.commit()
```

I've installed pyodbc using pip and have it as a folder where the py file is. both the py file and the pyodbc folder are added to a zip file that I've uploaded to Lambda functions Console. When I test the function I receive an error:

```
START RequestId: XXX Version: $LATEST
Unable to import module 'detect_last_sample': No module named 'pyodbc'

END RequestId: XXX
REPORT RequestId: YYY   Duration: 1.24 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 21 MB
```

Please help me understand what am I missing here. Many thanks!

--EDIT
 Looks like there's more to this issue then simply creating a zip with the external libs, there is an issue with pyodbc itself when used in aws lambda.
Anyway during my searches I found this repo containing pre complied libraries including pyodbc : https://github.com/Miserlou/lambda-packages

Good luck to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your zip file probably isn't structured properly. Did you establish a virtual environment when you pip installed your dependency and specify the correct version of Python?

Create one folder that contains (i) your code and (ii) the contents of the "site-package" folder - then zip the "contents" of the folder up (not the folder) and upload. Like this:

1) Create your virtual environment

```
python3.6 -m venv /path_where_you_want_a_virtual_env/
```

2) Activate your virtual env:

```
$source my_env/bin/activate
```

3) Install your dependency inside your virtual env:

```
python3.6 -m pip install pyodbc
```

AWS supports either 2.7 or 3.6.  If you do not install the dependency in the correct folder it will not be there.

4) Copy the contents of the site-packages folder to a folder of your choice (can be found at /lib/python3.6/site-packages). Personally I use a file manager to do this.

5) Copy your .py script to the same folder.

6) Zip the contents of the folder (not the folder itself)

```
zip -r myzipfile.zip *
```

Go to the AWS management console and upload this zip file.

Seriously, its cream cheese once you've done it once ;-)

Additional edits:

(A) The main routine in your .py script should begin exactly like this:
    def lambda_handler(event, context):

(B) In the AWS Lambda function GUI you need to set the lambda handler as my_py_script_name.lambda_handler (i.e. just lose the .py and add .lambda_handler)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I've done all these steps, and now I have a different error: "Unable to import module 'detect_last_sample': No module named 'detect_last_sample'
". I've created a new lambda function, called it detect_last_sample. In the py file the only function is called detect_last_sample, and the handler of lambda function is detect_last_sample.detect_last_sample. Please help me understand what is wrong here.

Comment: It looks like the lambda function is not being called properly. Naming the script and the lambda handler routine the same thing is a little confusing. Please can you post your new script?

Comment: Hi. I should mention my Os is Win 10. My virtual envis C:\Users\Ehud\Envs\l1 and it  has a folder named Lib/site-packages. I copied it's contents to a different folder (C:\LambdaVEnv), added the single py file to it, and zipped it with this: c:\ZipExe\zip.exe -r C:\LambdaVEnv\l1.zip * . the handler is back to lambda_handler as shown in the question itself. Something is missing in the pip install, but I cant see what.

Comment: Perhaps the virtual env is wrong, the command I use is "mkvirtualenv C:\LambdaVEnv\new_test\l2", and I receive this "'python.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.", but it is created anyway

Comment: I dont recognise that error. If the packages are being installed in the site-packages directory then that should be fine.  Please see my edits to my original answer.